# Como ajustar a posição da bolinha num gráfico de régua entre as medidas -100, 0, 100 dentro do canvas?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas

Tem um gráfico que tem medidas que vão de **-100 a 0** e **0 a 100**. O que preciso fazer é ajustar o cálculo da posição da bolinha com o número de acordo com a entrada **gradientDataChart** que pode ser um valor entre -100 e 100, o problema é de proporcionalidade, dependendo da tela, a bolinha está sumindo, estava usando a distancia 16, mas só funcionou para largura de 586px;

Eu testei [por aqui se isso puder facilitar](https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/moveTo/_sample_.playable_code.html).

Escrevendo apenas esse código, eu usei 38 pra 900 de largura, o problema é que se mudar pra 1000, já sai da posição... precisa ser responsivo.

```
  var largura = 900, medida = -100, medidaPosicao = 38 * ((medida / largura) * 100);
      ctx.beginPath();
      canvas.width = largura;
      ctx.translate(medidaPosicao, 0);
      var centerX = canvas.width / 2; 
      var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
      ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, 24, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      ctx.fillStyle ="#ffffff";
      ctx.fill()
      ctx.font = 'bold 14pt sans-serif';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.strokeStyle ='#622BCF'
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fillStyle ="#622bcf80"; 
      ctx.fillText(`${medida}`, centerX, centerY+8);
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
```

**Esta é a imagem:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML:**

```
<canvas class="gradient" id="canvas_gradient_chart" height="70">
```

**Código typeScript:**

```
 positionXChart(size, number, distance) {
      //como ajusto isso pra executar a posição correta 
      return distance * ((number/size) * 100);
 }

 renderGradientChart(gradientDataChart) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_gradient_chart") as HTMLCanvasElement;

    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.width = rect.width;
      canvas.height = 70;
      ctx.beginPath();
    
      var centerX = canvas.width / 2; 
      var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
     
      const radian = 24;
      const area = canvas.width * canvas.height / 2;
     // var centerY = this.positionXChart(canvas.width, this.gradientDataChart);
      const newPosition = this.positionXChart(canvas.width, this.gradientDataChart, area);
      //aqui ele faz o posicionamento dentro do canvas  
      ctx.translate(newPosition, 0);
     
      ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radian, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      ctx.fillStyle ="#ffffff";
      ctx.fill()
      ctx.font = 'bold 14pt sans-serif';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.strokeStyle ='#622BCF'
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fillStyle ="#622bcf80";  // <-- Text colour here
      ctx.fillText(`${gradientDataChart ? gradientDataChart : 0}`, centerX, centerY+8);
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
       ctx.save();
      ctx.restore();
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.gradient {
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #5ADC7E,#5E93E3,#F02752);
   height: 70px !important;
   border-radius: 10px;
   width: 100%;
}
.area-chart-gradient {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 95%;
}
.legend-gradient {
    font-family: 'Roboto Regular';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #4E506B;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.tooltip-chart {
    position: absolute;
    &.hide-chart {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A solução é dividir a soma do total de pontos, ou seja temos 100 de um lado e 100 do outro lado do zero: -100 e 100 (200), vezes a porcentagem + valor entre -100 e 100:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawCircle(width, metric, distance) {
  var X = width/200+distance * (metric + 100 + (distance / 2))
  var Y = canvas.height / 2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(X, Y, 18, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillText(metric, X, Y);
}

drawCircle(canvas.width, -100, 20)
drawCircle(canvas.width, -50, 20)
drawCircle(canvas.width, 0, 20)
drawCircle(canvas.width, 25, 20)
drawCircle(canvas.width, 100, 20)
```